# WiFi Connection problems Samsung Galaxy S3 mini

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, connection-issues

I have a Samsung Galaxy s3 mini. The wi-fi is turned on and the phone is not detecting my Trendnet 3G router at home. All my other devices e.g. laptop and BlackBery's are connecting seamlessly with the router, but not the S3 mini. How do I ascertain that the phone's wifi is working correctly. There are no other routers in range to cross reference with those.

Comment: Does the Blackberry support creating a wireless hotspot? You could try that and see if your S3-Mini is detecting that. There's also PC software available to create hotspots (as e.g. Connectify for Windows) -- however, they mostly generate ad-hoc networks Android does not natively support *connecting*, though it should *detect* them.

Comment: Hi Izzy, I am installing connectify. Will keep you updated on outcome. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

I have had the exact problem on galaxy s3. Did everything I read on the forums from rebooting phone, router,modify router settings e.t.c. I'll cut to the chase I simply went on the playstore and installed an app called Wi-Fi fixer which resolved the problem straight away and I haven't had any problems since.
Hope this helps